# Error while trying to print PPIDS in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hello i am trying to recursevely print PPID's (parent, grandparent and so on). I wrote a function:

```
function parents(){
    smth=$(ps -o ppid= -p "$1")
    echo $smth
    if test "$smth" = "1"; then
        echo "Top process"
    else
        parents $sth
    fi
}
read -p "Enter PID:" upid
parents $upid
```

when i run the script i get the error:

```
error: list of process IDs must follow -p
```

I have no idea what im doing wrong.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a trace of execution with variables shown.

Comment: Have you tried using the `pstree` command?

Comment: i thought about it but i dont know how to do it with recursion sinc i have to use recursion

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your script:

1. You're calling `parents` with variable `$sth` instead of `$smth`
2. The output of `ps -o ppid= -p "$1"` contains space characters which makes your test fail. Change the quoted `"$smth"` in the test to `$smth`.

```
function parents(){
    smth=$(ps -o ppid= -p "$1")
    echo $smth
    if test $smth = "1"; then
        echo "Top process"
    else
        parents $smth
    fi
}
```

Comment: if i remove the quotes in the test i get the unary operator expected error